# Transação com Entity Framework. Grava 2 vezes após erro

Tags: entity-framework-6, transações

Estou usando transação para realizar as alterações no banco. Meu problema está quando dá algum erro na hora de salvar.

Se houver erro na hora de inserir a movimentação ele trata da forma correta não salvando nada no banco. Porém, quando volta pra tela, eu arrumo o problema (que foi o tamanho do campo na base) e faço a inserção novamente, só que ele grava 2 vezes os registros do banco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    public override void Add(NotaFiscalItem obj)
    {
        using (var transaction = Db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                ItemMovimentacao mov = new ItemMovimentacao();
                mov.Numero_Item = obj.Numero_Item;
                mov.Origem_ItemMovimentacao = "Inclusão de Item de NF";

                Db.NotaFiscalItens.Add(obj);
                Db.ItemMovimentacoes.Add(mov);

                Db.SaveChanges();

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Ou seja, ele gera o erro esperado para o problema de overflow no banco, mas, quando volta pra tela eu mando executar de novo (já com o problema resolvido), ele grava de novo aquilo que ele não conseguiu gravar na primeira vez.

Comment: Qual o motivo pra usar repositórios?

Comment: Estou usando um projeto seguindo DDD. Tudo desacoplado. Então, tem a camada de repositório, serviço, dominio.

Comment: `Porém, quando eu volto, arrumo e executo novamente` isso debugando?

Comment: Sim. Na verdade só mudo o tamanho do campo na tabela para provocar o erro. Depois volto ao tamanho normal e executo de novo.

Comment: É por isso mesmo que não funciona. [Veja estas respostas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+entity+framework+n%C3%A3o+reposit%C3%B3rio). Não sei quem te falou pra usar assim, mas está tremendamente errado.

Comment: Cigano. Qual parte está errado? Eu uso o repositório apenas para configurar e realizar as operações básicas do EF.

Comment: Está errado. EF é um repositório. Você não leu nada do que eu colei aqui?

Comment: Li Sim. Mas estamos falando de um problema técnico certo? O que você está sugerindo é uma mudança na implementação do conceito. Até ai teríamos que discutir mais um pouco, como por exemplo, toda a configuração do banco, sem ser no repositório, ficaria no domínio? Até acho que você tem razão, preciso absorver mais um pouco. Mas quando ao problema técnico, em tese, não faz diferença se está em N camadas ou não certo?

Comment: Só uma questão. Não vejo onde a resposta da pergunta informada como duplicada responde a minha. Não tenho problema de duplicar o contexto. Provavelmente seja o contrário. Inclusive testei fazer com transação no contexto direto, sem usar TransactionScope e o resultado é o mesmo. Ele parece armazenar o deu erro e gravar 2 vezes quando não houver erro. Vou editar a pergunta inclusive com essas informações

Comment: Faz diferença sim, e ainda acho que você não leu o que eu eu coloquei pra você. O EF não admite "separação por camadas". O que você fez é usar dois contextos (em dois repositórios diferentes), criando o problema do contexto destacado, que é a mesma coisa da pergunta que marquei lá. Pare de reinventar a roda. Utilize o contexto dentro do *Controller* sem separar em repositórios.

Comment: Se você editar sua pergunta e colocar só a segunda parte (com a edição), posso responder. Aí coloco pra reabertura.

Comment: Pergunta alterada. Obrigado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32853/discussion-between-marcelo-monteiro-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).